# SQLite: Calculating percentage of number of entries that match multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sqlite

I feel like I'm missing something super obvious here. I've read tons of threads and Googled my butt off, but I can't figure out how to get this code to work, though I've come close a couple of times.

I'm working off a table that has a few columns. I need to select the items that match two criteria and calculate the percentage of the whole that match that criteria and round the percentage using printf (I cannot use ROUND). I haven't tried using printf yet because I can't even get the percentage to calculate.

For example, a table called movies:

```
------------------------------------
id     |     title     |     score
-----------------------------------
1      |   War Movie   |      51
2      |   Pony Movie  |     100
3      |   Big Wars    |      55
4      |   Bad Movie   |      12
5      |   Big Heist   |      90
6      |   Total War   |      19
```

I want to pull all the movies that have a score > 50 and "war" in the title. In this case, it would return 33.33 ("War Movie" and "Big Wars" match the criteria; 2 / 6 = 33.33%).

Of all the things I've tried, I think this comes closest:

```
FROM movies
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(title) AS s FROM movies) t
WHERE score > 50 AND title LIKE '%war%'
GROUP BY title
```

A couple of things go wrong with this:

1. The COUNT(*) returns a 1 in each column (instead of 6 - i.e. the total of all records in the table)
2. % of total returns (null)

This also feels close:

```
SELECT title,
        SUM(title) * 1.0 / Count(title) * 100 AS Percentage
        FROM movies
        WHERE score > 50 AND title LIKE '%war%'
        GROUP BY title
```

But this just returns the percentage as 0.

I'm stumped!

Comment: Idk if sqlite is different or what, usually if you use like you would lower/upper the case to make it the same as your like or where condition.

Comment: @Mukyuu yes, `like` is case-sensitive but AFAIK sqlite can set to insensitive, but a lower-case function `lower()`  can always get a insensitive result.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean "title" would be in all caps? The WHERE clause in the code seems to be working fine; both of those queries return War Movie and Big Wars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to pull all the movies that have a score > 50 and "war" in the title.

If I understand correctly, you want conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when score > 50 and title like '%war%' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio
from movies;
```